# Largest number of NDC characters

Tags: database, med-symbol-abbreviations, ndc-ntl-drug-codes, healthcare-data

I'm trying to set the data type for NDC codes in a database, with a length on the data type.

When reading about National Drug Codes (NDC), I'm finding that most codes are either 10 or 11 characters.  The wikipedia page doesn't have a max number of digits listed.  But I have found 12 characters NDC codes online, with dashes.

Looks like the VA software wikipedia page says NDC codes can have more than 16 characters!  But I have not found any data that shows this.

http://www.vistapedia.com/index.php/NDC_Rules

Is there a standard on NDC codes (for healthcare data) that's published anywhere?  Seems like the standard keeps changing.  I realize RxNorm is more of a standard, so I'm simply looking for an NDC standard if possible.